# IE issue with menu hover

Tags: javascript, css

Site: http://bit.ly/Pa3xJS

Using IE (9 or lower), when hovering over any menu on the homepage and trying to select items 2+, ie: hover over Shop and try click Brushes or Haircare, the menu disappears.

I suspect this is due to my slidecontent, however everything I have tried (CSS hacks and JS changes) doesn't let the menu work as it should and does on FF, Chrome & Safari.

Is there a specific IE fix for this or a CSS hack that I've missed?

Edit: I've updated Justus' CSS fiddle to include the slidecontent without the irrelevant bits of code - http://jsfiddle.net/eN7sh/14/. Feel free to play with that, just looking for what the issue is on IE.. mainly IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Your website has a lot of other code, so it's hard to see what really is causing the issue. I have fiddled a css-only 3-level menu a while ago: http://jsfiddle.net/eN7sh/12/

I'm pretty sure it will work if you can match the `css`/`html`, although `li:hover` might not work on IE7. You can just use javascript to add a classname on the `hover` event and work with that, if you must.
Fiddle code:
HTML:

```
<ul class="main">
  <li ><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link two</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sublink one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sublink two</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub sublink one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub sublink two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.main {
}
.main li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.main ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 1em;
}
.main li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.main ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.main ul ul {
    left:100%;
    top: 0;
​}​
```

Comment: Thank you, Justus. I've updated your fork [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eN7sh/14/) does that help in trying to sort out the issue? Still can't work it :(

Comment: Well, I gave this example as a starting point and guidance for expanding menu's. I'm not able to help you out by digging through all your resources, but I think you want to isolate a working version, and add in other parts of your website / application until you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i checked your site on ie 8.its working fine ..

just one thing you should do

apply

z-index property on sub menu item.

Comment: Thank you Anuj, but IE9 is the main concern. z-index on the fiddle isn't the issue, it's fine on the main site.